# Convert to LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

Simple line:

```
var x = (from a in arr select a).First();
Console.WriteLine(“First" + x);
```

How to convert to Lambda expression?

Comment: () => arr.First() ? The first line and second line do not seem to be in sync - do you have an error in the code snippet ?

Comment: Your first line is just var x = arr.First() and i don't know what your last variable refer to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to convert the LINQ query from using query syntax to plain extension method calls?

```
// var first = (from a in arr select a).First();
var first = arr.First();

// var last = (from a in arr select a).Last();
var last = arr.Last();

// var filtered = (from a in arr where a == 10 select a).First();
// there are a couple of ways to write this:
var filtered1 = arr.Where(a => a == 10)
                   .First();
var filtered2 = arr.First(a => a == 10); // produces the same result but obtained differently

// now a very complex query (leaving out the type details)
// var query = from a in arr1
//             join b in arr2 on a.SomeValue equals b.AnotherValue
//             group new { a.Name, Value = a.SomeValue, b.Date }
//                 by new { a.Name, a.Group } into g
//             orderby g.Key.Name, g.Key.Group descending
//             select new { g.Key.Name, Count = g.Count() };
var query = arr1.Join(arr2,
                      a => a.SomeValue,
                      b => b.AnotherValue,
                      (a, b) => new { a, b })
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.a.Name, x.a.Group },
                         x => new { x.a.Name, Value = x.a.SomeValue, x.b.Date })
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key.Name)
                .ThenByDescending(g => g.Key.Group)
                .Select(g => new { g.Key.Name, Count = g.Count() });
```

Comment: Yeah what's the advantage of using query syntax vs plain extension method calls? Yur code is shorter than mine then why use query based expressions at all

Comment: also what would I do if the expression read (from a in arr where a == 10 select a).First();

Comment: @learning: You won't see any of the advantages of it here for such a simple query.  You'll see that it will be easier to read _especially_ if you have a very complex query including joins, groupings, sorting, etc.

Comment: @learningdb: Your particular example doesn't require any query-comprehension semantics, so it wouldn't benefit from them. Other queries would, e.g., `from a in arr where a != 0 let b = somefunc(1.0/a) where b < 1 select new {a, b}`.

Comment: I'll come up with a complex query to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an expression of the form `(from y in x select y)`, you can almost always write `x` instead.

Comment: that isn't *quite* true; in that case it still calls `.Select(x=>x)`, which doesn't have to return *quite* the same thing. Interestingly, it *doesn't* call `.Select(x=>x)` if you do a `where` (etc) followed by a trivial projection, but it **does** if the projection is the **only** thing you do.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I should know better than to make *wild* generalisations on this forum. :-P. I've amended my answer with the appropriate qualifiers.

Comment: In case you're wondering why it does that, it's to ensure that the query doesn't just return the original collection.  Eric Lippert explains it in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/12/trivial-projections-are-usually-optimized-away.aspx).